# CSS not working in Firefox but works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox

The following code works in Chrome, but fails in Firefox. This style blinks the success message.

```css
.rainbow {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2), color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22));
  background-image: gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2), color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22));
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="rainbow">Success</div>
```

Comment: Typo use = next to class

Comment: as far as i know background-clip is not supported in ff.

Comment: Though the linked question refers to the `-moz` prefixed version, the answer is all the same. `background-clip` is a standard property but the value `text` is not. It is a Webkit specific option and so won't work in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

i think for firefox support u need to write something like this.

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
}
```

```html
<div>A rainbow made from a gradient</div>
```

see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) for more

for making gradient colors i always use [this tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Op wants to use rainbow text rather then text in rainbow box.. please don't change the moto/aim of question.. thanx

Answer (score 0):

Better use [this](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'%5C-moz%5C-linear%5C-gradient%5C%28left%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28248%5C%2C80%5C%2C50%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%200%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28241%5C%2C111%5C%2C92%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2019%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28246%5C%2C41%5C%2C12%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2051%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28240%5C%2C47%5C%2C23%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2071%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28231%5C%2C56%5C%2C39%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%20100%5C%25%5C%29%5C%3B') tool to generate the gradient you want because the way you have used it its not recognized by mozilla.

While `background-clip: text;` will not work on mozilla because i doesnt exists.

Comment: Well, please check your own code before posting as answer as its not working..

Comment: @Leothelion did you tried and didnt work for you ?

Comment: yes please..check in ff and you will see